# How to remove grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using google colab for my project. I am getting grid lines on images even I am not writing them.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('k15.jpg')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

for code like above, I am getting grid lines which is not the case when I run the same code in my python shell.

Comment: The code you show is probably not the one responsible for the gridlines. Do they still appear if you start with a fresh kernel?

Comment: yes.I think its something related to google colab. it's weird....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently something in the background changes the style. I have no experience whatsoever with google colab ti judge whether this can be responsible for the observed difference in displayed image.

In any case it should be possible to manually turn the grid lines off on a per notebook basis.

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False

# rest of code
```

Comment: That's finally solved my problem. I was looking for somehow to stop this but couldn't find any. Thanks!!

Answer (score 28):

```
plt.imshow(myImage)
plt.grid(None)   <---- this should remove that white grid
```

Comment: Actually, plt.grid() will also remove the grid, so dont have to even type 'None'

Comment: This worked very well, until I tried adding a twin axis at the top of my plot with `ax.twiny()`. Now none of the methods here work anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a different packet, you can pretty much do it easily with PIL or Pillow

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('C:\...\k15.jpg')
img.show()
```

Comment: When you open it in PIL you need to provide the entirety of the image's path

Comment: there is no path as I am using it on google colab. also, same script is working fine on local python shell.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me in an Jupyter Notebook.
Here is an alternative solution - after **every** `imshow` you need to disable the grid like this:

```
...
plt.imshow(image)
plt.grid(False)
...
```