# Extract plot lines from chart

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, computer-vision

I am trying to extract some plot lines from the image below. As you can see one line is quite thin. My idea was to remove the noise around the lines (grid lines and text).

[image]

So far I came up with this code to remove the grid:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('test.png')

edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=0.01,theta=np.pi/90, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=80)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 255, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',gray)
```

After that i get the following result:
[image]

As you can see, there is still some noise around the plots and they are a bit cut off (doesn't have to be perfectly). Has anyone a better solution or some tips how i can improve this? Maybe remove the words first? Maybe detect the lines directly instead of removing the grid etc.?

Comment: Remove the grid lines from the chart.. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543885/how-to-remove-grid-lines-on-image-in-python

Comment: the grid lines are already on the images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can segment both plots using the [HSV color space](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) and looking for the blue and orange color. This results on a pretty clean binary mask. Let's check out the code:

```
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Set image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "graphs.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = readImage(path + fileName)

# BGR to HSV:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

The first portion of the script converts the `BGR` image to the `HSV` color space. Next you need the color values to apply a simple binary thresholding. The tricky part is to get correct [HSV values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48528754/what-are-recommended-color-spaces-for-detecting-orange-color-in-open-cv/48533523#48533523).  For the blue graph, a proper `Hue` threshold seems to be from `[85, 179]` while leaving the rest of the channels opened, from `[0, 255]`. For the orange color, a possible `Hue` range could be `[11, 30]`. I create a list with these two thresholds:

```
# Array with HSV values:
hsvValues = []

# Blue range:
lowThreshold = [85, 0, 0]
highThreshold = [179, 255, 255]
# Into the list:
hsvValues.append((lowThreshold, highThreshold))

# Orange range:
lowThreshold = [11, 0, 0]
highThreshold = [30, 255, 255]
# Into the list:
hsvValues.append((lowThreshold, highThreshold))
```

Now, let's create the mask. Just iterate over the `HSV` list and apply the thresholding using the [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) function:

```
# Create mask:
for i in range(len(hsvValues)):
    # Get current thresholds:
    currentLowThres = np.array(hsvValues[i][0])
    currentHighThres = np.array(hsvValues[i][2])

    # Apply HSV threshold:
    hsvMask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, currentLowThres, currentHighThres)
    cv2.imshow("Hsv Mask", hsvMask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

These are the two masks:

Blue plot:

[image]

Orange plot:

[image]

Now, do you want to create actual line models using this information? That's another problem. I'd be cautious to use `Hough's line transform/detection`. Although the masks are pretty clean, Hough's line parameter tuning is notoriously *capricious* (i.e., difficult and non-scalable) if you attempt to run not-so similar images through the algorithm, Additionally, I guess you could be more interested in multiple lines segments per plot instead of one continuous line, so I'd be on the lookout for a more ad-hoc approach.

Comment: thanks for the comment. My use case is to separate lines from the background noise to be able to calculate the width of the line. For my understanding your method would only work if the lines are colored? with a black and white image this would not work right?

Comment: Do you actually have black white images as well? I converted your image to a grayscale one and played around with several filters. the thick (former orange) line can be detected very nicely, but the (former) blue one is more difficult. However, if your have grayscale images, it could work with a simple thresholding, if the lines are different from the grid line gray values.